# Using Tinymce in Angular2 project

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'm trying to embed **tinymce** into my website which is built using Angular2. 
Following is my component:

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
    //some code

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    // some code
    }

    ngOnInit():any {
    tinymce.init(
        {
            selector: ".tinymce",
        });
    }
}
```

And in side my html, there is:

```
<textarea class="tinymce" rows="15"></textarea>
```

But there is error saying "`Cannot find name 'tinymce'`" but I have already include

```
<script src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
```

inside the head of html. 
Did I do something wrong? Is my initialization incorrect?

Comment: are you using a module loader like webpack or systemJS?

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I've used for myself, on RC6. First I'll show the usage:

```html
<h1>The Editor</h1>
<textarea htmlEditor [(ngModel)]="txt"></textarea>
<h1>The HTML Source</h1>
<textarea [(ngModel)]="txt"></textarea>
<h1>The Rendered HTML</h1>
<div [innerHTML]="txt"></div>
```

So the usage is pretty simple and straightforward, the HTML result of the editor is moved to the value of the `textarea` (I trigger the update on `blur` event)

And here's the directive definition (Typescript):

```js
import {
    Directive,
    OnDestroy,
    AfterViewInit,
    Provider,
    forwardRef,
    HostBinding
} from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var tinymce: any;

export const TinyMceValueAccessor: Provider = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => TinyMceDirective2),
    multi: true
};

// Tinymce directive
@Directive({
    selector: '[htmlEditor]',
    providers: [TinyMceValueAccessor]
})

export class TinyMceDirective2 implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    static nextUniqueId = 0;
    @HostBinding('attr.data-tinymce-uniqueid') uniqueId;

    onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => { };
    onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = () => { };
    innerValue;
    init = false;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.uniqueId = `tinymce-host-${TinyMceDirective2.nextUniqueId++}`;
    }

    //get accessor
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log('tinymce');
        tinymce.init({
            selector: `[data-tinymce-uniqueid=${this.uniqueId}]`,
            schema: 'html5',
            setup: ed => {
                ed.on('init', ed2 => {
                    if (this.innerValue) ed2.target.setContent(this.innerValue);
                    this.init = true;
                });
            }
        });

        // I chose to send an update on blur, you may choose otherwise
        tinymce.activeEditor.on('blur', () => this.updateValue());
    }

    updateValue() {
        const content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
        this.value = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    }

    writeValue(value): void {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
            if (this.init && value) tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(value);
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn): void {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn): void {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.init) tinymce.remove(`[data-tinymce-uniqueid=${this.uniqueId}]`);
    }
}
```

Some highlights:

- I'm using `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` to provide for two way binding using `ngModel`
- I'm assigning a unique id to a custom attribute on the host element so that tinymce only initializes that specific element and no others.
- I'm sending value updates only on `blur` events, but you may use a different strategy, for example using debounce time.
- I'm using `DomSanitizer` to bypass sanitization, since tinymce sometimes outputs html which triggers Angular 2 sanitization.

Comment: Been trying this one out. I'll get an error on page reload saying inline template:25:0 caused by: tinymce is not defined - any idea as to why?

Answer (score 3):

I have a nice working plunker using Angular2 and TinyMCE using

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/E5Yzk9KT9nSWlPU6i1ZK?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Angular v4 final. Here's how I implemented the TinyMCE editor:

**tiny-editor.component.ts**

```
imports...

declare var tinymce: any;

const contentAccessor = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TinyEditorComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tiny-editor',
  styleUrls: ['./tiny-editor.component.scss'],
  providers: [contentAccessor],
  template: `
      <textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>
  `
})
export class TinyEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  private onTouch: Function;
  private onModelChange: Function;

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onModelChange = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.editorContent = value;
  }

  @Input() elementId: String;
  @Output() onEditorContentChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  editor;
  editorContent: string = null;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: `#${this.elementId}`,
      plugins: ['link', 'table'],
      skin_url: '../assets/skins/lightgray',
      schema: 'html5',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup change', () => {
          const tinyContent = editor.getContent();
          this.editorContent = tinyContent;
          this.onEditorContentChange.emit(tinyContent);
          this.onModelChange(tinyContent);
          this.onTouch();
          console.log(tinyContent);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**create-article.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<app-tiny-editor
   formControlName="content"
   [elementId]="'my-editor'">
</app-tiny-editor>
```

This *seems* to be working, although when rendering out the form.value there's some delay in the content showing.

Comment: As of about May, I've switched over to the Editor from PrimeNG which uses Quill.js as its editor. The angular integration seems to be much better.

Comment: Thanks for the update :) I was going to use TinyMCE but seemed a huge bother to get the value out again. Good call on PrimeNG I am liking it thanks.

Comment: This throw a error: ```text-editor.component.ts:59 Uncaught TypeError: _this.onModelChange is not a function``` on ```this.onModelChange(content);```