# TinyMCE in Angular2 final - problems on reload

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am tryig to get TinyMCE to work in my angular2 project. I've created a tinymce.directive as shown in Aviad P's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521392/using-tinymce-in-angular2-project)

The directive is loading fine in mye view, until I reload the view, after which I get an Exception:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ThreadComponent class ThreadComponent - inline template:26:0 caused by: tinymce is not defined
```

My directive is a straight copy of the one in before mentioned question, and I load it on the page with

```
<textarea htmlEditor [(ngModel)]="txt"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your  `ThreadComponent` `(ThreadDirective is best practice)` in a module

```js
import { ThreadDirective } from '(your directive path)';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ThreadDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can use your directive